# How do I create a plain white bar for a website that sits on top of every page at the top?

Tags: html, css, web, wordpress

This is the website that I'm trying to recreate - http://www.ulta.com/

I'm trying to replace the search bar with just a plain white bar with few words on text on it. It needs to be on every page just like on http://www.ulta.com/.

I'm using Wordpress for the website, and fairly new to HTML/CSS.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare a Div with position:fixed in CSS.

Comment: Thanks. Do you mind explaining a little more, I'm new to CSS/HTML. Where would I declare this? In my .css file? How do I make sure it comes on every page?

Answer (score 0):

In CSS, put the "position: fixed;" for the position/div that you are trying to fix at the top.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following div to the header.php file just after the  tag.

```
<div class="topFixedBar">Some text</div>
```

and add the following to your style.css file.

```
.topFixedBar
{
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    height: 30px;
}
```

The above should show a white bar at the top of every page (you can change the background color/height to whatever your requirements are.